# using IF condition inside a while loop in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I have a problem with my C# code. I have created a login form in C# 2010. When I am validating the user name, I used an *if-condition* inside the *while loop* but the thing is that even when the username and password are correct, it executes the *else-statement*. Please help me to solve this.

Here is my code :

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string connection=
        @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" 
        +" AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ResturantDB.mdf;"
        +" Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True";

    SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection(connection);

    try {
        cn.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception) {
        // print the exception's message?
        MessageBox.Show("Connection to Database failed; check Connection!");
    }

    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Login]", cn);
    cmd.Connection=cn;
    SqlDataReader reader=null;
    reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read()) {
        if(
            txtuser.Text==(reader["Username"].ToString())
            &&
            txtpass.Text==(reader["Password"].ToString())
            ) {
            //MessageBox.Show( "logged in!" );
            Home newhome=new Home();
            newhome.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentials!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have only one row in your Login table?

Comment: First: it appears that you store passwords in plain text. Don't! There are plenty of questions about password hashing and salting here on SO. please read them carefully. Second: you don't want to query *all* rows in your Login-Table. Just the one that corresponds to the given `Username`. Then only check that once. Don't use a loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will solve it on this way:

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ResturantDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Conncetion to Database faild check Connection !");
    }

    while (true)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Password] FROM [Login] WHERE [Username] = '" + txtuser.Text + "'", cn);
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (!reader.HasRows)
            MessageBox.Show("User does not exist. Please, try again.");
        else
        {
            //username should be unique, so only one row is possible to have
            reader.Read();
            if (txtpass.Text == (reader["Password"].ToString()))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("loged in!");
                    Home newhome = new Home();
                    newhome.Show();

                    this.Hide();
                    return;
                }
            else
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentian..! Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the comments to @crapple's answer. Use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and as @comecme said, you might run into problems if one `Username` has several `Password`s.

Answer (score 3):

you should use a break, when a username is found in your if condition like

```
bool found = false;
while (reader.Read())
{   
  if (txtuser.Text == (reader["Username"].ToString()) && txtpass.Text == (reader["Password"].ToString()))
  {
    //MessageBox.Show("loged in!");
    Home newhome = new Home();
    newhome.Show();              
    this.Hide();
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (!found)
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentian..!");
```

you get into the else block because if any login is not correct, the messagebox appears and that is in n-1 cases in your code.

Comment: thank you hoffmanuel its really helped and i did it now its work fine thank you..!!

Comment: you're welcome. but i suggest to not use plain text passwords as Corak mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if **all** users have the same user name and password. You need to refine your SQL to select only that one user. Also, please read into password hashing for the sake of your users.

Answer (score 2):

Because its in a loop.

create a bool variable. update its value in loop (if found same username and password) and check outside based on its value.

Do this

```
bool found;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (txtuser.Text == (reader["Username"].ToString()) && 
        txtpass.Text == (reader["Password"].ToString()))
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }                
}
if (found)
{
    MessageBox.Show("loged in!");
    Home newhome = new Home();
    newhome.Show();

    this.Hide();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentian..!");
}
```

Comment: This would work, if by chance the first found record is the one with the correct username (and password). Better would be `"SELECT * FROM [Login] WHERE Username = @Username"`. And then `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtuser.text)`

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest and Secure method**

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select uname, pswd from [Login] where uname =@uname and pswd =@ps", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uname", "username here"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ps", "pasword here"));            
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read()) 
        {
             //MessageBox.Show( "logged in!" );
            Home newhome = new Home();
            newhome.Show();

            this.Hide();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "Incorrect credentials!" );
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to loop thru the records for your case
use this query, compate username and password in the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Login] where Username='" + txtuser.Text "' and password = '"  + txtpass.Text + "'"
```

Comment: For the sake of all that's good and holy, please use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: Theoretically it could be that a user can have multiple passwords.

Comment: @comecme - indeed, but that would not be relevant, because for a login you only want to know if there exists at least one valid login for the provided username and password. If there are more than one, but not *that specific* one, then login fails.

Comment: @Corak Sorry, I didn't see you also included the password in the query. Only saw you included the Username.